# get the position of every element with xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to add the number of every `element` with xslt.
My XML is structured like this:

```
<root>
    <element1/>
    <element2/>
    <element3/>
</root>
```

It shoud be displayed int the browser like this:

```
[1] element1
[2] element2
[3] element3
```

I tried it with `<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>` but with this, the number is doubled somehow and looks like this:

```
[2] element1
[4] element2
[6] element3
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another possibility to get the actual position of every `element`?

Here is my XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/root/*">
    <p>
    <xsl:element name="div">
    [<xsl:value-of select="position()" />]
            <xsl:attribute name="class">entry<xsl:value-of select="@type"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why don't you post your XSLT code, so that we can correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is doubling because of `text()` nodes. Try using `xsl:number` instead...

```
<div>[<xsl:number count="*"/>] <xsl:value-of select="name()"/></div>
```

Also, you can't put `xsl:attribute` where you have it now because you've already output children of the element. You could do something like this instead (although you won't get the name with the `xsl:apply-templates`)...

```
<p>
    <div class="entry{@type}">
        [<xsl:number count="*"/>]
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</p>
```